# GCDAsyncSocket : how to connect to a user?

Tags: ios, unix, ssh, port, gcdasyncsocket

I am using this library to connect to my UNIX host address, if i specify host address like aix.polarhome.com i can connect with it via – `connectToHost:onPort:withTimeout:error:`

```
[gcdAsyncSocket connectToHost:[website host] onPort:port withTimeout:-1 error:&error];
```

but if i need to connect to UNIX with ssh i have to specify the username with the address also like xyz@aix.polarhome.com and also with the customised port other than 22.

So how can i accomplish this. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

SSH is a big complicated protocol on top of TCP. You need to use an SSH library to make an SSH connection.

Check out the [libssh2-for-iOS project](https://github.com/x2on/libssh2-for-iOS) to get started.